# Is there a gnuplot setting to interpret ints as floats?

Tags: gnuplot

gnuplot has the well-known gotcha of integer division, so `1/2 = 0`. Float literals are one solution: `1./2` or `1/2.`.

I use gnuplot as a calculator, e.g. `pr 1/2` (`print` abbr), and it's easy to forget the `.`, and there's no warning. I've never actually wanted integer arithmetic.

Is there a setting to force floating point arithmetic --- to interpret integers as floats?  (to have in my `~/.gluplot` config)

Comment: Definitive answer: No there is not.

Comment: You already have a clear and definite answer. This is one of the most annoying pitfalls in gnuplot. It would be nice if gnuplot could use `1/2` for float and `1//2` for integer division.

Comment: @theozh I disagree, gnuplot follows the behavior that the C language has for ages. Adding some kind of new operator would for sure introduce some other pitfalls.

Comment: And Fortran before that. gnuplot was written by programmers, for programmers. Hence the command line interface and all the operator rules.

Comment: @kebs & Dan Sp., yes, well, that's how it is. Of course, you can always argue: "it always has been like this", but this doesn't necessarily mean that it is intuitive. But I'm sure, Fortran- and C-people at that time had a good technical reason for this. In general, it's always easier to accept something when you know about the background and the thinking behind it. Do you maybe have a link explaining this?

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this issue, when we are using literals it is simple to just use decimal notation as noted in the comments above. A simple hack when using variables is to subtract by 0.0:

```
mynumber = 3
print mynumber/2 # 1
print (mynumber-0.0)/2 #1.5
```

Comment: Well, that's one way. If you are not sure if a variable is an integer or floating point and you want to ensure floating point division, you could also use `real(mynumber)/2`. Check `help real`.